# How to define a friend function operator>> inside a local class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend-function, local-class

Trying to overload input operator `>>` inside a local class. I tried to define `friend istream &operator >>` inside `class Data`.

```
int readFile(char* file_name,float temperature_data[][31])
{
    class Data
    {
        public:
            int day,month,year;
            float temp;
            friend istream & operator >> (istream &in,  Data &c)
            {
                char ch;
                in >> c.day;
                in >>  ch;
                in >> c.month;
                in >>  ch;
                in >> c.year;
                in >>  ch;
                in >> c.temp;
                return in;
            }
    };
    freopen(file_name,"r",stdin);
    int i;
    Data d;
    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        int total=0;
        char ch;
        cin>>d;
        temperature_data[d.month-1][d.day-1] = d.temp;
        ch = getchar();
        if(ch==EOF)
            break;
    }
    fclose(stdin);
    return d.year;
}
```

It's showing error:

```
error: can't define friend function 'operator>>' in a local class definition
```

Comment: A function can be defined in a friend declaration of a class if and only if the class is a non-local class (9.8), the function name is unqualified, and the function has namespace scope.

Comment: Is there any workaround? I'm trying to overload >> operator for input. I have to do this inside function readFile. Thanks

Comment: The workaround is to not use `operator>>`, rather make a `read(istream& in)` method, and call it by `d.read(cin)`.

Comment: I'm trying to follow your suggestion, Eljay. If you can give me example of how to use `read(istream& in)`, it will be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'm thinking, from my comment, which you'd call with `d.read(cin)`:

```
class Data {
public:
  int day,month,year;
  float temp;
  void read(istream& in) {
    char ch;
    in >> day;
    in >> ch;
    in >> month;
    in >> ch;
    in >> year;
    in >> ch;
    in >> temp;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks..it worked. Is it possible by overloading `operator >>` ?

Comment: No, as per JLev's comment, you cannot do that because you have a local class.